# How to write a script with nautilus actions?

Tags: gnome, bash, gnome-terminal, mp4, nautilus-actions

I want to use nautilus actions with my own script which I have usually started successfully with open-terminal and pasting the command (s. below) directly in the terminal.

```
for file in *.mp4; do mkdir "${file%.mp4}"; mv "${file}" ./"${file%.mp4}"; done
```

Using nautilus config tool now, I do not know how to insert the command in the dedicated field (see picture 1) or how to write an adequate bash script file (see picture 2). Can someone give a hint?

**Picture 1: attempt to load script (below) over .gnome2/nautilus-scripts** 
[image]

**Picture 2: attempt to write a script**
[image]

Comment: You're splitting the `mv` command over 2 lines: don't do that.

Comment: Ah, this was just a avoidable copy 'n' paste mistake. Thank you, Glenn! But it gives me the following error message (in spanish): mv: no se puede efectuar `stat' sobre «*.mp4»: No existe el fichero o el directorio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved with `cd $(dirname $(readlink -f $0))`, see [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349105/bash-script-set-current-working-directory-to-the-directory-of-the-script). :)

Answer (score 0):

You're in a directory with no mp4 files. When a glob pattern (like `*.mp4`) does not match any files, the pattern is treated as a literal string (`"*.mp4"`)

In bash you do this to replace a pattern that matches no files with the empty string:

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

So, it seems that your script is not running in the directory you think it should be running in. You might want to add a `echo $PWD` line to debug.

Comment: Thank you very much, Glenn, that you take your time to answer to me! But I am not quite sure if I can follow: Why would the command in question function when I use it by copy 'n' pasting it into a terminal which I led via cd to the directory with the mp4 inside, but would not when I use the bash script above which I have used in the same directory with the mp4 file inside?

Comment: When nautilus runs it, how sure are you what directory the script is running in? Do you think you know, or are you sure you know?